# Cosmos DB - SQL - Get All Unique Array Items and a count

Tags: sql, json, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a cosmos db made up of items such as

```
{
    "id": 1
    "countries": [
    "Australia", 
    "New Zealand"
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2
    "countries": [
    "Australia", 
    "Antarctica"
    ]
}
```

I know I can get a distinct result of the values by doing

```
SELECT DISTINCT country FROM country IN t.countries
```

which returns data like

```
    {
        "country": "Australia"
    },
    {
        "country": "New Zealand"
    },
    {
        "country": "Antarctica"
    }
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE country FROM country IN t.countries
```

which returns just an array like

```
['Australia', 'New Zealand', 'Antarctica']
```

How would I create a query to get data such as

```
    {
        "country": "Australia",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "country": "New Zealand",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "country": "Antarctica",
        "count": 1
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this with GROUP BY,

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(r) as Total,r as Country 
FROM c JOIN r IN c.countries 
GROUP BY r
```

and the results,

> [
> {
> "Total": 1,
> "Country": "Antarctica"
> },
> {
> "Total": 1,
> "Country": "New Zealand"
> },
> {
> "Total": 2,
> "Country": "Australia"
> } ]

Comment: Thank you so much! That has given me the result i am looking for - Sidenote if two items have the same total, or at least for the first result it is grouping the "Country" field as another array, such as {"Total": 1, "Country" : ["Bhutan", "Nepal"]}, I can easily work around this in the code but is it possible to have each country individual as well?

Comment: you can apply a distinct to get that, btw upvote if this helped